# XSL - remove the duplicate node but keep the original

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, duplicates

Need help in removing the duplicate node from the input xml using XSLT

This is how my XML looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<NodeA NodeAattr="123">

<NodeB NodeBattr="456"></NodeB>

<NodeC>
    <NodeD="ValueD">
       <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
          <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF >
       </NodeE >
       <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
          <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF >
       </NodeE>
  </NodeD>
</NodeC>
</NodeA>
```

My final output should look like

```
<NodeA NodeAattr="123">

<NodeB NodeBattr="456"></NodeB>

<NodeC>
    <NodeD="ValueD">
       <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
          <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF>
       </NodeE >
    </NodeD>
</NodeC>
</NodeA>
```

Here the Name attribute of Node E has duplicate values. Based on this attribute I need to eliminate the duplicate.

It would be really helpful if someone could help me with the XSLT required here to get the output.
I can only use the XSLT 1.0

Comment: Will the duplicate elements always have the same parent element? If two NodeE elements have the same name, but different parents, does that count as duplicates?

Comment: @Tim C Yes, the duplicate elements will have the same parent

Answer (score 1):

If two `<NodeE>` elements are considered duplicates only if they have the same parent, this is probably the simplest solution:

#### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<NodeA NodeAattr="123">

  <NodeB NodeBattr="456"></NodeB>

  <NodeC>
    <NodeD Name="ValueD">
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF>
      </NodeE>
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
    <!-- Added another <NodeD> element for demonstration -->
    <NodeD>
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF>
      </NodeE>
      <NodeE Name="ValueDEF">
        <NodeF Value="0"></NodeF>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
  </NodeC>
</NodeA>
```

#### Stylesheet #1

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--
  Identity transform: copy elements and attributes from input file as is
  -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
  Drop <NodeE> elements with a preceding <NodeE> sibling that has the same
  @Name attribute value as the current element
  -->
  <xsl:template
    match="NodeE[preceding-sibling::NodeE[@Name = current()/@Name]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output #1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NodeA NodeAattr="123">
  <NodeB NodeBattr="456"/>
  <NodeC>
    <NodeD Name="ValueD">
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"/>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
    <NodeD>
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"/>
      </NodeE>
      <NodeE Name="ValueDEF">
        <NodeF Value="0"/>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
  </NodeC>
</NodeA>
```

On the other hand, if `<NodeE>` elements should be considered duplicates across the whole document, you can use Muenchian grouping:

#### Stylesheet #2

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kNode" match="NodeE" use="@Name"/>

  <!--
  Identity transform: copy elements and attributes from input file as is
  -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
  Use Muenchian grouping to apply unique NodeE elements.
  See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html
  -->
  <xsl:template match="NodeE[generate-id() = 
                       generate-id(key('kNode', @Name)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Drop other <NodeE> elements -->
  <xsl:template match="NodeE"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output #2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NodeA NodeAattr="123">
  <NodeB NodeBattr="456"/>
  <NodeC>
    <NodeD Name="ValueD">
      <NodeE Name="ValueABC">
        <NodeF Value="0"/>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
    <NodeD>
      <NodeE Name="ValueDEF">
        <NodeF Value="0"/>
      </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
  </NodeC>
</NodeA>
```

Comment: @ Eero It works like a charm. Thanks a ton. But I have one more question in mind. For instance, if I want to remove only the duplicate node whose 'Name' attribute value is "ValueABC", how this will be restructured? I dont want to touch the other nodes whose 'Name' attributes' values are "ValueDEF", "ValueGHJ"

Comment: For stylesheet #1, the change is pretty simple, just add a predicate to narrow down the node set: `<xsl:template match="NodeE[@Name = 'ValueABC'][preceding-sibling::NodeE[@Name = current()/@Name]]"/>`. For #2, you could do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5362145). There might be a simpler solution for #2, but that's what popped into my mind first.

Comment: On a similar note, could you provide me with your comments on this one as well ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020026/xsl-combining-values-of-siblings-if-values-of-an-attribute-is-same

Answer (score -1):

Use "deep-euql" function to compare two item(). Check this one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NodeE">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="deep-equal(self::NodeE, following-sibling::NodeE)"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think that `deep-equal` is available in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Peter is correct: `deep-equal()` is only available in XPath 2.0.