# Grouping values with same attributes using xslt-1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Given this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<agrisResources xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <agrisResource bibliographicLevel="AM" ags:ARN="^aSF17^b00003">
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio harveyi</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject>
            <ags:subjectClassification scheme="ags:ASC">ASFA-1</ags:subjectClassification>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Fish diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
        </dc:subject>
    </agrisResource>
</agrisResources>
```

I would like to group items with the same attributes, so the output would be like this:

```
<dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae||Vibrio harveyi||Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
<dc:subject>
    <ags:subjectClassification scheme="ags:ASC">ASFA-1</ags:subjectClassification>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases||Fish diseases||Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
</dc:subject>
```

Basically, my rule for the grouping is to combine the values of the nodes if that node have multiple values, eg `dc:subject`, and `ags:subjectThesaurus`. I specify in my title to **group values with same attributes** because I'm not really sure if it is possible to just group them by their tags without specifying their attributes to differentiate them.

In other words, differentiate

```
<dc:subject>Penaeidae</dc:subject>
```

from

```
<dc:subject>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus>Bacterial diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
</dc:subject>
```

**UPDATE**

**INPUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<agrisResources xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <agrisResource bibliographicLevel="AM" ags:ARN="^aSF17^b00003">
        <dc:creator>
            <ags:creatorPersonal>Doe, John</ags:creatorPersonal>
            <ags:creatorPersonal>Smith, Jason T.</ags:creatorPersonal>
            <ags:creatorPersonal>Doe, Jane E.</ags:creatorPersonal>
        </dc:creator>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio harveyi</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject>
            <ags:subjectClassification scheme="ags:ASC">ASFA-1</ags:subjectClassification>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Fish diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
        </dc:subject>
    </agrisResource>
</agrisResources>
```

**Desired Output**

Rules on grouping: Combine the values using double pipe `||` as separator for repeating elements, eg `<ags:creatorPersonal>`, `<dc:subject xml:lang="en">` and `<ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">`. Leave other elements as is that does not meet that rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<agrisResources xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <agrisResource bibliographicLevel="AM" ags:ARN="^aSF17^b00003">
        <dc:creator>
            <ags:creatorPersonal>Doe, John||Smith, Jason T.||Doe, Jane E.</ags:creatorPersonal>
        </dc:creator>
        <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae||Vibrio harveyi||Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject>
            <ags:subjectClassification scheme="ags:ASC">ASFA-1</ags:subjectClassification>
            <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases||Fish diseases||Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
        </dc:subject>
    </agrisResource>
</agrisResources>
```

Below is my code based from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023219/1919069%22answer%22):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
            xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/"
            xmlns:agls="http://www.naa.gov.au/recordkeeping/gov_online/agls/1.2"
            xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ags:subjectThesaurus|dc:subject">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | text()"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="NextSibling"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ags:subjectThesaurus[@scheme = preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ags:subjectThesaurus]/@scheme]|dc:subject[@xml:lang = preceding-sibling::*[1][self::dc:subject]/@xml:lang]"/>

    <xsl:template match="ags:subjectThesaurus|dc:subject" mode="includeSib">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('||', .)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="NextSibling"/>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="NextSibling">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::ags:subjectThesaurus and @scheme = current()/@scheme]|following-sibling::*[1][self::dc:subject and @xml:lang = current()/@xml:lang]" mode="includeSib"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My only problem is that it is only transforming the `ags:subjectThesaurus` but not the `dc:subject` node. My output looks like this:

```
<dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae</dc:subject>
<dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio harveyi</dc:subject>
<dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
<dc:subject>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases||Fish diseases||Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
</dc:subject>
```

How can I modify my code such that it will also group the `dc:subject` node with the same `xml:lang` attribute?

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestion of [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034747/1919069) to use the Muenchian method, below is what I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
            xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/"
            xmlns:agls="http://www.naa.gov.au/recordkeeping/gov_online/agls/1.2"
            xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNodeSubject" match="dc:subject[@xml:lang]" use="@xml:lang"/>
    <xsl:key name="subjectThesaurus" match="dc:subject/ags:subjectThesaurus" use="@scheme"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dc:subject[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kNodeSubject', @xml:lang)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNodeSubject', @xml:lang)" mode="concat"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dc:subject/ags:subjectThesaurus[generate-id() = generate-id(key('subjectThesaurus', @scheme)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('subjectThesaurus', @scheme)" mode="concat"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dc:subject|subjectThesaurus" mode="concat">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dc:subject"/>
    <xsl:template match="ags:subjectThesaurus"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I applied the code above, the nodes `ags:subjectThesaurus` are gone and the values of `<dc:subject xml:lang="en">` are not grouped either. I don't know if I have the match right, I used the `match="dc:subject[@xml:lang]"` for the `<xsl:key name="kNodeSubject"` because the node `ags:subjectThesaurus` is the child of `<dc:subject>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you pick a better starting point: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k, please see my updated post, I'm not sure what to use to match `<dc:subject>` and `ags:subjectThesaurus`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. There's no `ags:subjectThesaurus` in the posted input.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, in my example input there are 3 `ags:subjectThesaurus` node eg `<ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>`. The other values of `ags:subjectThesaurus` are `Fish diseases` and `Genes`.

Comment: But there is no root element and the prefixes are not bound to a namespace. IOW, your code cannot be run as is.

Comment: I should also add that it's not clear what your rules for grouping are.

Comment: Re your update: Why does `ASFA-1` not appear in the output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the `<ags:subjectClassification scheme="ags:ASC">ASFA-1</ags:subjectClassification>` node? I would like to copy that as is and that node is not really relevant for my use case. I will edit my post to include that in the output. There are a lot of other elements that I exclude in my sample input (not relevant for my use and to only show the relevant portion) and I would like to copy them as is.

Comment: I get the impression you merely want to join nodes **of** certain type, not group them **by** type. The difference being that there will be only ever one "group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/">
  <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio harveyi</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xml:lang="fr">Franca premier</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xml:lang="fr">Franca deux</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Fish diseases</ags:subjectThesaurus>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Genes</ags:subjectThesaurus>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:B">Bees</ags:subjectThesaurus>
    <ags:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:B">Birds</ags:subjectThesaurus>
  </dc:subject>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="subj-by-lang" match="dc:subject[@xml:lang]" use="@xml:lang"/>
<xsl:key name="thes-by-scheme" match="ags:subjectThesaurus" use="@scheme"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- group subjects by lang -->
        <xsl:for-each select="dc:subject[@xml:lang][count(. | key('subj-by-lang', @xml:lang)[1]) = 1]">
             <dc:subject xml:lang="{@xml:lang}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('subj-by-lang', @xml:lang)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </dc:subject>  
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- process other nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::dc:subject[@xml:lang])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dc:subject">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- group thesauri by scheme    -->
        <xsl:for-each select="ags:subjectThesaurus[count(. | key('thes-by-scheme', @scheme)[1]) = 1]">
             <dc:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="{@xml:lang}" scheme="{@scheme}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('thes-by-scheme', @scheme)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </dc:subjectThesaurus> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/">
  <dc:subject xml:lang="en">Penaeidae||Vibrio harveyi||Vibrio parahaemolyticus</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject xml:lang="fr">Franca premier||Franca deux</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>
    <dc:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:ASFAT">Bacterial diseases||Fish diseases||Genes</dc:subjectThesaurus>
    <dc:subjectThesaurus xml:lang="en" scheme="ags:B">Bees||Birds</dc:subjectThesaurus>
  </dc:subject>
</root>
```

---

### Added:

Based on your clarifications, I suspect you want to do something much simpler: just join together some leaf nodes (i.e. nodes with no child elements) and leave the others as is.

Here's an example joining the `dc:subject` leaf nodes within `agrisResource`:

```
<xsl:template match="agrisResource">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- join subjects with no children -->
        <dc:subject>
            <!-- copy the attributes of the first subject with no children -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="dc:subject[not(*)][1]/@*"/>
            <!-- concat the values of all subjects with any attributes -->
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:subject[not(*)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </dc:subject>  
        <!-- process other nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::dc:subject[not(*)])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This could be generalized by using a key based on an element's name.

Comment: P.S. Do note that keys work across the entire document. If you want to group nodes only within their parent element, then you must also  include the parent's unique id in the key.

Comment: I have updated my input example with root elements and prefixes bound to a namespace. Please note that I only use the `xml:lang` attribute because I am not sure if it is possible to differentiate `dc:subject` without child nodes. In my real xml input file, there are no instance where `xml:lang` is not equal to `en`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply your latest xsl code in my sample input xml, the output is this: `<agrisResource xmlns:ags="http://purl.org/agmes/1.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><dc:subject xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:agls="http://www.naa.gov.au/recordkeeping/gov_online/agls/1.2" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"/>PenaeidaeVibrio harveyiVibrio parahaemolyticusASFA-1Bacterial diseasesFish diseasesGenes</agrisResource>`.

Comment: Great! By the way, you have this line to process other nodes: `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::dc:subject[not(*)])]"/>`. How can I modify it such that it will **NOT** process other nodes eg `dc:subjectThesaurus` and `dc:creator`? Please see what I've tried to accomplish this: http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNr/3. Many thanks again.

Comment: You can add more conditions to the predicate, e.g. `not(self::a or self::b)]`. Comments are not a convenient place to answer follow-up questions.