# remove duplicate nodes from xml file using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xmlnode

I am looking for a solution to delete all duplicates from an XML file not based on Exact node name, Instead, I am looking for a solution that can identify all the duplicate nodes and delete them. Only the first node should  exist, and the rest of the duplicate nodes to be deleted.

I read couple of similar posts:

[XSL - remove the duplicate node but keep the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924211/xsl-remove-the-duplicate-node-but-keep-the-original)

[Removing duplicate elements with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912544/removing-duplicate-elements-with-xslt)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<projects>
        <project id="staticproperties">
            <property name="prop1">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>       
            <property name="prop2">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>               
            <property name="prop3">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>       
            <property name="prop4">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>   
            </project>
        <project id="febrelease2013">
            <property name="prop">testing prop from pom.xml</property>
            <property name="prop1">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>   
            <property name="prop3">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>       
            <property name="prop1">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>               
            <property name="prop5">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>   
        </project>
</projects>
```

NOTE: `<property name="**could be any thing**">`

Desired Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<projects>
        <project id="staticproperties">
            <property name="prop1">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>       
            <property name="prop2">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>               
            <property name="prop3">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>       
            <property name="prop4">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>   
            </project>
        <project id="febrelease2013">
            <property name="prop">testing prop from pom.xml</property>      
            <property name="prop5">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>   
        </project>
</projects>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this via XSLT 1.0 is by utilizing the [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) methodology to output only unique `<property>` elements (based on their `@name` attribute).

For example, when this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="property" use="@name"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
    match="property[
             not(
               generate-id() =
               generate-id(key('kPropertyByName', @name)[1])
             )
           ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...is applied against the provided XML, the wanted result is produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
  <project id="staticproperties">
    <property name="prop1">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>
    <property name="prop2">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>
    <property name="prop3">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>
    <property name="prop4">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>
  </project>
  <project id="febrelease2013">
    <property name="prop">testing prop from pom.xml</property>
    <property name="prop5">removing this prop if its duplicate</property>
  </project>
</projects>
```